# how to convert a nested loop to lapply in r

Tags: r, nested-loops, lapply

I have a list named "dahak" that contains 30000 number between 1 to 10. I want to check every number with all of the number in the list, if two numbers are equals then append number 1 to weight_list, if two numbers are not equals then calculate their difference and store it as x and append x to the weight_list.
Here is the code:

```
for(j in 1:num_nodes){
  for (k in 1:num_nodes){
    if(j==k){
      weight_list <- c(weight_list,0)
    }
    else if(as.numeric(dahak[j])==as.numeric(dahak[k])){
      weight_list <- c(weight_list,1)
    }
    else if(as.numeric(dahak[j])!=as.numeric(dahak[k])){
      x = 1 - (abs(as.numeric(dahak[j]) - as.numeric(dahak[k])) / 10)
      weight_list <- c(weight_list,x)
    }
  }
}
```

How can i optimize this code? and how can i do this with lapply?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example so that others can test

Comment: Not clear without a reproducible example.  May be `v1 <- unlist(dahak); outer(v1, v1, FUN = '==')`

Comment: What is `num_nodes`? Also, is the second `if` statement supposed to be an `else if`? As it is written in the example, if `j==k` and `dahak[j]==dahak[k]`, the `weight_list` will have both `0` and `1` appended in the same iteration.

Comment: @akrun dahak list is like this: [1,1,2,6,4,3,3,3,2,3,1,2,] ... my code haven't error, but it takes a long time for run ... I use the wight_list to create a matrix and then, use matrix for create a network ... if you want the all code, i can sen it to you

Comment: @JasonKLai num_node is the same as the length of dahak ... the second if statement is else is, thanks

Comment: You have asked how to optimize your code because it takes a long time to run. Besides [Allan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60121674/3817004) below, here are 3 hints: (1) Growing a vector in a loop is very time consuming as the data is copied over and over again. Better allocate a vector beforehand and update single elements by subsetting. (2) The last two `if` clauses are needless because your formula returns `1` anyway if `dahak[j] == dahak[k]` (3) Pull the coersion of `dahak` to numeric out off the loop instead of repeating this for single elements within the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a 30,000 x 30,000 matrix. It also sounds like `dahak` is a vector rather than a list. If that's *really* what you want to do, you can simplify your logic and vectorize like this;

```r
get_weights <- function(x)  1 - abs(x - as.numeric(dahak))/10 
weights <- do.call(rbind, lapply(as.numeric(dahak), get_weights)) - diag(length(dahak))
```

Using the same dummy data as @ThomasIsCoding I get:

```
weights
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
#>  [1,]  0.0  0.9  0.7  0.3  1.0  0.4  0.3  0.6  0.6   0.8   1.0   0.9   0.6   0.9   0.5
#>  [2,]  0.9  0.0  0.8  0.4  0.9  0.5  0.4  0.7  0.7   0.7   0.9   0.8   0.7   1.0   0.6
#>  [3,]  0.7  0.8  0.0  0.6  0.7  0.7  0.6  0.9  0.9   0.5   0.7   0.6   0.9   0.8   0.8
#>  [4,]  0.3  0.4  0.6  0.0  0.3  0.9  1.0  0.7  0.7   0.1   0.3   0.2   0.7   0.4   0.8
#>  [5,]  1.0  0.9  0.7  0.3  0.0  0.4  0.3  0.6  0.6   0.8   1.0   0.9   0.6   0.9   0.5
#>  [6,]  0.4  0.5  0.7  0.9  0.4  0.0  0.9  0.8  0.8   0.2   0.4   0.3   0.8   0.5   0.9
#>  [7,]  0.3  0.4  0.6  1.0  0.3  0.9  0.0  0.7  0.7   0.1   0.3   0.2   0.7   0.4   0.8
#>  [8,]  0.6  0.7  0.9  0.7  0.6  0.8  0.7  0.0  1.0   0.4   0.6   0.5   1.0   0.7   0.9
#>  [9,]  0.6  0.7  0.9  0.7  0.6  0.8  0.7  1.0  0.0   0.4   0.6   0.5   1.0   0.7   0.9
#> [10,]  0.8  0.7  0.5  0.1  0.8  0.2  0.1  0.4  0.4   0.0   0.8   0.9   0.4   0.7   0.3
#> [11,]  1.0  0.9  0.7  0.3  1.0  0.4  0.3  0.6  0.6   0.8   0.0   0.9   0.6   0.9   0.5
#> [12,]  0.9  0.8  0.6  0.2  0.9  0.3  0.2  0.5  0.5   0.9   0.9   0.0   0.5   0.8   0.4
#> [13,]  0.6  0.7  0.9  0.7  0.6  0.8  0.7  1.0  1.0   0.4   0.6   0.5   0.0   0.7   0.9
#> [14,]  0.9  1.0  0.8  0.4  0.9  0.5  0.4  0.7  0.7   0.7   0.9   0.8   0.7   0.0   0.6
#> [15,]  0.5  0.6  0.8  0.8  0.5  0.9  0.8  0.9  0.9   0.3   0.5   0.4   0.9   0.6   0.0
```

Comment: that's right, i want to create a 30,000 * 30,000 matrix, but it's not get the right answer ... check with this data and the final answer ... dahak list is `[9,1,4,3,2]` and matrix must be`V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 0 0.2 0.5 0.4 0.3
2 0.2 0 0.7 0.8 0.9
3 0.5 0.7 0 0.9 0.8
4 0.4 0.8 0.9 0 0.9
5 0.3 0.9 0.8 0.9 0`

Comment: @omidjahadi that's the answer I get with the modified version above

Comment: i have this error after run the program with 30000 data ... `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 292 Kb`

Comment: @omidjahadi you are trying to write a matrix with 900000000 entries, so you may not have enough memory. You could try restarting the R session

Comment: @omidjahadi My computer can't hold 900 million values in memory either. Why do you need such a large matrix? Is there a different approach you could use?

Comment: I want to create a network and then apply community detection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207441/discussion-between-omid-jahadi-and-allan-cameron).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be the simplification you are looking for, where `outer` and `ifelse` are used.

Below is an example with dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
num_nodes <- 15
dahak <- sample(10,num_nodes,replace = TRUE)
```

If you want a matrix for `weigth_list` of dimensions `num_nodes`, then you can try

```
weight_list <- (u<-ifelse((z<-abs(outer(dahak,dahak,FUN = "-")))!=0,1-z/10,1))-diag(diag(u))
```

such that

```
> weight_list
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,]  0.0  0.5  0.8  0.2  0.3  0.8  0.3  0.4  0.2   0.6   0.6   0.9   0.7   0.9   0.8
 [2,]  0.5  0.0  0.7  0.7  0.8  0.7  0.8  0.9  0.7   0.9   0.9   0.4   0.8   0.4   0.7
 [3,]  0.8  0.7  0.0  0.4  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.6  0.4   0.8   0.8   0.7   0.9   0.7   1.0
 [4,]  0.2  0.7  0.4  0.0  0.9  0.4  0.9  0.8  1.0   0.6   0.6   0.1   0.5   0.1   0.4
 [5,]  0.3  0.8  0.5  0.9  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.9  0.9   0.7   0.7   0.2   0.6   0.2   0.5
 [6,]  0.8  0.7  1.0  0.4  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.6  0.4   0.8   0.8   0.7   0.9   0.7   1.0
 [7,]  0.3  0.8  0.5  0.9  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.9  0.9   0.7   0.7   0.2   0.6   0.2   0.5
 [8,]  0.4  0.9  0.6  0.8  0.9  0.6  0.9  0.0  0.8   0.8   0.8   0.3   0.7   0.3   0.6
 [9,]  0.2  0.7  0.4  1.0  0.9  0.4  0.9  0.8  0.0   0.6   0.6   0.1   0.5   0.1   0.4
[10,]  0.6  0.9  0.8  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.7  0.8  0.6   0.0   1.0   0.5   0.9   0.5   0.8
[11,]  0.6  0.9  0.8  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.7  0.8  0.6   1.0   0.0   0.5   0.9   0.5   0.8
[12,]  0.9  0.4  0.7  0.1  0.2  0.7  0.2  0.3  0.1   0.5   0.5   0.0   0.6   1.0   0.7
[13,]  0.7  0.8  0.9  0.5  0.6  0.9  0.6  0.7  0.5   0.9   0.9   0.6   0.0   0.6   0.9
[14,]  0.9  0.4  0.7  0.1  0.2  0.7  0.2  0.3  0.1   0.5   0.5   1.0   0.6   0.0   0.7
[15,]  0.8  0.7  1.0  0.4  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.6  0.4   0.8   0.8   0.7   0.9   0.7   0.0
```

Comment: Please, review your anwer. I believe there are two flaws: (1) The diagonal is not set to zero, (2) `abs()` has been omitted, so the resulting `weight_list` contains values outside the range [0, 1]. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks! I was not aware of expected output from OP's code, so some important information is miss from the post description. Now the answer is updated